# How to match updated values with previously saved ones and hilight the changes?

Tags: c#, string, search, compare

I need to search mismatch values against already stored column values in a database and mark them as red. In this case, I indicate that this word is mismatch from the previously saved value.

My scenario is that I have a text area where user can update the values of a particular column.

When the user updates the value, at the same time I need to check that text area values against the previously saved values and mark only mismatch values as red.

I have this

```
string savevalues="this is great searching c#"; // get from database column

string textareavalue="this is greater search with c#"; //TextArea1.InnerText.ToString(); // get from text area which user entered.
```

When the user clicks on the update button, the result should be printed like this: `"this is greater search with c#"`.

I want that input string and the compared one to be red only on the different words `"greater"` and `"search"`.

What would be the best way to compare two string values according to this requirement?

if extra word added in middle so i need to color it also.
ex.  string savevalues="this is great searching c#"; 
     string textareavalue="this is greater search with c#";

in example above result should be result="this is greater search with c#";
means "greater" "search" should be red color and extra word like "with" should be in other color say yellow.

Comment: do you want to show the inflections of the words in the first string that appear in the second string?

Comment: What would you expect to happen in case a word has been added intirely, in the middle? Like you added "with" but completely ignored it in the compare? Refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+diff&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.morganstanley%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-a).